# remove blank lines using java code

Tags: java, pdf

Below is my Java code which is used to create a `PDF` and print the content in the `PDF` document. I have blank lines between the printed lines as shown in the code below. If there are more than two blank lines after the printed statement, just write one blank line and omit other blank lines to write in the `PDF` document. So if there is one or two blank lines I can print it as it is, but if there are more than that then remove all extra blank lines and just add one blank line using Java code. I am using Java version 5. Please suggest.

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Document document = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        try {
            final String prefix = "test";
            final File temporaryPDF = File.createTempFile(prefix, ".pdf");
            document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);

            fos = new FileOutputStream(temporaryPDF);

            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fos);
            document.open();

            Font font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURIER, 10);

            List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
            lines.add("This is first line.");
            lines.add("This is second line.");
            lines.add(" ");
            lines.add(" ");
            lines.add(" ");
            lines.add(" ");
            lines.add("This is third printed line.");
            lines.add(" ");
            lines.add("This is fourth printed line.");
            lines.add(" ");
            lines.add(" ");
            lines.add(" ");
            lines.add("#ACC004342-123");
            lines.add(" ");
            lines.add(" ");
            lines.add(" ");
            lines.add(" ");
            lines.add(" ");
            lines.add(" ");
            lines.add("More information:");
            lines.add("This is fifth printed line.");
            lines.add("#ACC004342-123");
            lines.add("");
            lines.add("This is Sixth printed line.");
            lines.add("Some information goes here.");

            for (final String line : lines) {
                document.add(new Paragraph(12, line, font));
            }

            document.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

PS: I again raised this post for more clarity. Thanks.

Comment: Hmmmm, don't *insert* the empty lines in the first place? Either that, or this question is still not very clear...

Comment: If there are more than two empty lines just show two empty lines..dont insert more than two empty lines if any. @ppeterka

Comment: If a line contains only whiltespace you can check with [String#trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) `string.trim().length == 0`

Comment: I tried everything.If there are one or two blank lines i need to print them but if there are more than two blank lines i just need to print two blank lines , i was looking some efficient  way to do this using java code. Is there any way? Can u answer with the code so that if it works i can accept your answer. @Jhonny007

Comment: Are you looking for code that will clean up the lines variable before the for loop starts? That's what it *seems* like you want. Maybe?

Comment: @javaUser I have given you an answer to the question you asked below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a minimal answer that should resolve your problem. I did reduce the code to the necessary parts since I needed to test it myself and I didn't have access to classes you used.

You should make the code in the question as [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as possible when asking a question, so it is easier to recreate.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    lines.add("This is first line.");
    lines.add("This is second line.");
    lines.add(" ");
    lines.add(" ");
    lines.add(" ");
    lines.add(" ");
    lines.add("This is third printed line.");
    lines.add(" ");
    lines.add("This is fourth printed line.");
    lines.add(" ");
    lines.add(" ");
    lines.add(" ");
    lines.add("#ACC004342-123");
    lines.add(" ");
    lines.add(" ");
    lines.add(" ");
    lines.add(" ");
    lines.add(" ");
    lines.add(" ");
    lines.add("More information:");
    lines.add("This is fifth printed line.");
    lines.add("#ACC004342-123");
    lines.add("");
    lines.add("This is Sixth printed line.");
    lines.add("Some information goes here.");

    //count empty lines
    int emptyLineCounter = 0; 

    for (final String line : lines) {
        //when empty line increment counter, else reset counter
        if(line.trim().length() == 0) 
            emptyLineCounter++;
        else
            emptyLineCounter = 0;

        //when more then 2 empty lines are encountered move ignore line
        if(emptyLineCounter <= 2)
            System.out.println(line); //add line to document
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Others having written wrong answers is a direct result of not providing [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code.